# regex to separate paragraphs by double new line

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Making a tiny helper for authors to add/remove empty lines in textarea. The one that removes extra lines seems to work:

```
if(jQuery("#remove_line").prop("checked")){
        conver = conver.replace(/^\s*[\r\n]/gm,'');
    }
```

But there has to be a reverse one that makes any new line into double new line (no matter if there's just 1 or even 3 new lines in a row). E.g. this:

```
text
text



text

text
```

Should be processed into this:

```
text

text

text

text
```

Anyone can help with that? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can match one or more newlines `[\r\n]+` and replace with 2 newlines `\n\n`

```js
const regex = /[\r\n]+/gm;
const str = `text
text



text

text`;

console.log(str.replace(/[\r\n]+/g, `\n\n`));
```

Answer (score 0):

didn't test but i think this could work : `replace(/[\n]+?/g,'\n\n')`

\n+ will match 1 or more new lines, the question mark will force to take the shortest amount possible (this will stop the matching block at the first non new line character)

Comment: Nice, this seems to work! Not even sure which one would be more universal, this or the one sugested below, but either one works just fine. Thanks! :)

Comment: Did you test the pattern? Why make it non greedy `[\n]+?` ?

Answer (score 0):

The reverse?

```js
addEventListener('load', ()=>{
const ta = document.querySelector('textarea');
function doubleSpaceAfter(fullText, text, insensitive = true){
  const s = insensitive ? 'i' : '';
  return fullText.replace(new RegExp('('+text+')\\s+', 'g'+s), '\n\n$1\n\n');
}
ta.value = doubleSpaceAfter(ta.value, 'text here');
}); // end load
```

```html
<textarea>other stuff text here is this what you want? text here text here</textarea>
```

Comment: This breaks it down word by word :)) Which is fun, but not exactly what needs to be, as "text" is just example, but paragraphs are often long ones.